# lock a RaisedButton when another has been pressed RaisedButton

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have this code
I need to select only one option from the three buttons "Monthly, Quarterly and Yearly" and when selecting one, block the other two.

I have searched but I only find how to block the button that I just selected and I need to block the ones that are not selected.

these are the variables that I use to make it change color when selected.

```
bool pressMensual = false;
bool pressTrimes = false;
bool pressAnual = false;
bool _isPressed = false;



Container(
 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
 child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
   Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
    child: Column(
     children: [
      Text('PERIODO'),
      Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
       children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
         child: RaisedButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
          ),
          child: Text('MENSUAL'),
          color:  pressMensual ? Colors.blue[100] : Color(0xFF94D500),
          onPressed: () {
           _isPressed = true;
           setState(() {
            pressMensual = !pressMensual;
           });
          },
         ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
         ),
         color: pressTrimes ? Colors.blue[100]  : Color(0xFF94D500),
         child: Text('TRIMESTRAL'),         
         onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
             pressTrimes = !pressTrimes;
            });
         },
        ),
        RaisedButton(
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
         ),
         color: pressAnual ? Colors.blue[100] : Color(0xFF94D500),
         child: Text('ANUAL'),                        
          onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
            pressAnual = !pressAnual;
           });
          },
         ),
       ],
      ),
     ],
    ),
   );
```

Comment: Do you mean you like block the press fucntinality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way while others two will be false.
We like to set true on pressed button and make others false. In order to archive that, we need to update three values inside `setState` to update the UI.

```dart
  setState(() {
             pressMensual = true; // because `Mensual` is pressed here
             pressTrimes = false;
              pressAnual = false;
              });
```

**To lock the press Functionality**

Here we can pass `null` to prevent the tap-event of `RaisedButton` like `onPressed:null`. In that case we need to include another variable the way you did, or you can check those three `bool` variables.

Using `_isPressed` bool will be

```dart
           onPressed: _isPressed
                          ? null
                         : () {
                             setState(() {
                                  pressMensual = false;
                                  pressTrimes = true;
                                  pressAnual = false;
                                  _isPressed = true;
                                });
                              },
```

Or you can just do like and avoid using another bool.

```dart
          onPressed: pressMensual || pressTrimes || pressAnual
                            ? null
                            : () {
                                setState(() {
                                  pressMensual = false;
                                  pressTrimes = true;
                                  pressAnual = false;
                                });
                              },
```

**Using `null` will/can lose your style functionality** in that case instead of passing null to `onPressed` pass empty function like

```dart
                        onPressed: _isPressed
                            ? () {}
                            : () {
                                setState(() {
                                  pressMensual = false;
                                  pressTrimes = false;
                                  pressAnual = true;
                                  _isPressed = true;
                                });
                              },
```

**Full Widget**

```dart
 
class _TestWState extends State<STD> {
  bool pressMensual = false;
  bool pressTrimes = false;
  bool pressAnual = false;
  bool _isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('PERIODO'),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          child: Text('MENSUAL'),
                          color: pressMensual
                              ? Colors.blue[100]
                              : Color(0xFF94D500),
                          onPressed: _isPressed
                              ? null //* will loss style
                              : () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    pressMensual = true;
                                    pressTrimes = false;
                                    pressAnual = false;
                                    _isPressed = true;
                                  });
                                },
                        ),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                        color:
                            pressTrimes ? Colors.blue[100] : Color(0xFF94D500),
                        child: Text('TRIMESTRAL'),
                        onPressed: pressMensual || pressTrimes || pressAnual //* without using separate variable
                            ? () {}
                            : () {
                                setState(() {
                                  pressMensual = false;
                                  pressTrimes = true;
                                  pressAnual = false;
                                  _isPressed = true;
                                });
                              },
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                        color:
                            pressAnual ? Colors.blue[100] : Color(0xFF94D500),
                        child: Text('ANUAL'),
                        onPressed: _isPressed
                            ? () {}
                            : () {
                                setState(() {
                                  pressMensual = false;
                                  pressTrimes = false;
                                  pressAnual = true;
                                  _isPressed = true;
                                });
                              },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help it worked great for me! :)

Comment: Glad to help you out,